# How to make a playlist of streaming URLs?

Tags: audio-streaming, winamp, internet-radio

I like to listen to some radio stations, but when I want to play one I have to copy the URL from the text file and then go to the audio player (I use Winamp) and paste it in the open URL dialog box. Isn't there a way to put all the streaming URLs in a playlist to open it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I did it:

In an empty text file, list the stations in this structure:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF: <Station Title>
<Station URL>
#EXTINF: <Station Title>
<Station URL>
#EXTINF: <Station Title>
<Station URL>
```

Then save the file in m3u format.

Answer (score 0):

File > Play URL > Paste URL such as http://whyy.streamguys1.com/whyy-mp3 > on the now playing playlist pane on the right, you'll see your stream. Right click the stream > Send to > Add to Library, New Playlist, or chose Library Playlists if you already have one setup for your streams. I have used Library Playlists and can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press the "Add" Button on the left botton of the Playlist Editor. Then select "Add URL".

This works at least with Winamp 5.6.3